# How to set Autodesk Setting to front?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am having an app, which uses the Forge API. The UI displayed when pushing the Forge button "Settings" in "settingsTools group", overlaps one of my buttons.

However since my app zIndex is set (I am in react code) the click upon close of the setting UI, triggers my buttons instead of the close button.

Hence, I am intrested in setting the "Settings UI" to front so the click upon the close button triggers close. My front end code is in the react framework hence a simple zIndex parameter to set could do the trick.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of playing with hacky ways, consider using the docking panels provided by Forge Viewer. From my understanding, it can also [work with React](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-use-react-forge-viewer-dockingpanel).

To elaborate the usefulness of panels, consider the following example:

[image]

Here I have a floating div, showing me some information related to the model. Obviously I've set a high z-index, to bring it upfront and here I have the same problem as you have - when opening things like settings, properties, model tree, etc, they all appear behind my div. Moreover, when changing the size of the window, I have to deal with my div position.

On the other hand, Forge Viewer uses everywhere panels, like this very Settings dialog.

Thus, if you would place your button into this kind of panel, this would save you from headache with z-index, docking, rescaling etc, as all the panels are working nice one with each other, as the below Robot Control Panel:

[image]

For more information on how to create a panel, I suggest checking http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/panel

Comment: Hi Denis and sorry for the late reply. The solution suggested above would probably work if I have access to the UI of the toolbars. However the toolbar UI from "settings" is the setting dialogue provided by default from GuiViewer3D and I do not find how to access that UI. Is there an alternative solution to this issue?